# Why ONNX model reading is failing?

Tags: opencv, onnx

I'm working on model inference using opencv cuda dnn module. While reading  my onnx file using cv::dnn:: readNetFromONNX, I'm getting below message.

> Opencv(4.4.0-dev) Error: Unspecified error (> (expected:
> 'shape.depth() == CV_32S') where 'shapes.depth()' is 5 (CV_32FC1) must
> be equal to 'CV_32S' is 4 (CV_32SC1) in void_cdecl
> cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::ONNXImporter::populateNet(class
> cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net), file
> D:\opencv_test\newbuild\opencv-master\modules\dnn\src\onnx\innx_importer.cpp,
> line 1442

What could be the reason for this? If someone faced the similar issue and find any solution, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your input blob type must be CV_32SC1 (int) not CV_32FC1 (float).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I'm getting above error at 'readNetFromONNX()' api call. Below url is the code ,I used but readNetFromONNX is used instead of using 'readNet' as I'm reading .onnx extension file.https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d8d/samples_2dnn_2classification_8cpp-example.html#a15

Comment: You can check the model and blob types with https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron  tool. Or put your model here, so I could try to help you.

Comment: Sorry, Due to some restrictions I'm not able to provide my onnx file . So I did some experiment. Actually this onnx model converted for SegNet architecture. What I observed is this 'upsampling layer' present in network architecture is creating the issue. I'm able to read onnx file without upsampling layer. Is upsampling layer is supported in Opencv dnn?

Comment: This issue is fixed by using conv2DTranspose in the place of Upsampling2D api for SegNet network architecture layer. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633595/load-onnx-model-in-opencv-dnn

Answer (score 1):

Opencv `4.5+` should  solve the issue for me `4.5.1.48` worked.

Comment: In my case the issue was a typo in path of the onnx model